# jQuery doesn't work properly on Gutenberg blocks (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, highlight

I am trying to build a table to use as a block in Gutenberg (Wordpress).

I have got a very easy piece of code to work when I create the page as an HTML file. I have positioned called the .js file in the of the document and the before the closing body tag because I have read that is a good practice. However, I haven't got to always reproduce the same effect when the code is uploaded as a PHP file. I have been using Stock Lab to create my blocks, and the highlight effect works some of the times but not all. I use several instances of the same block for different types of content.

When the highlighting effect does work, it only works in one instance of the same block as you can see in this example, but not in the rest. In this case, it only works in the last instance but it used to be the first instance, not the last one when I have made other attempts at it.

I wonder if there is anything that I'm missing in my jQuery code that can make all instances of this element be interpreted as independent pieces if that is really the problem. The code below represents the exact same code I have been using in my Wordpress block. As you can see, it works on all instances of the table, whereas on the link provided earlier, it only modifies one of them.

What am I missing? How can I insert a piece of jQuery code on the Gutenberg block that reproduces independently across different instances of it?

Thanks.

```js
$('.row').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 30px 30px;
}
.table-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-left: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #ececff;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background: #fff;
}


.table-header {
  display: table-header-group;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #6c7ae0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0;
}

.cell {
display: table-cell;
}

p {
margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.row .cell {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;

}
.table-header .cell {
  font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1em;
  font-weight: unset !important;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.row .cell:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100% padding-left: 40px;
}

.row .cell:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%
}

.row:hover {
  background-color: #ececff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: #ececff;
}

.table, .row {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <ul class="table-header">
        <li class="cell">
          Title 01
        </li>
        <li class="cell">Title 02
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('a1');?></p>
        </li>
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('a2');?></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('b1');?></p>
        </li>
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('b2');?></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table">
      <ul class="table-header">
        <li class="cell">
          Title 01
        </li>
        <li class="cell">Title 02
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('a1');?></p>
        </li>
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('a2');?></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="row">
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('b1');?></p>
        </li>
        <li class="cell">
          <p><?php block_field ('b2');?></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $, Use jQuery keyword ($ will not call jquery in wordpress):

```
jQuery('.row').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```